# How to make a custom Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8, sysprep

What is the step-by-step way to make a custom Windows 8 installation ?

For example, with a minimal example, I would like an image which :

- Has a single user named "User"
- This user has Chrome and Firefox installed
- Has no link in the start screen except the desktop link
- Has no buttons on the task bar

I have tried to use sysprep but I lose user settings. The CopyProfile seems to apply Administrator's settings on programmaticaly created accounts, but does not preserve local users settings accross installations.

Comment: 1) Install Windows, made default user 'User' (make sure to not make that the computer name). 2) Install Chrome and Firefox. 3) Delete / remove the other links.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wait until Windows 8 is actually released.

I'm sure Microsoft is working on another update to their WAIK (Windows Automated Installation Kit). Or perhaps they will provide something completely new. I can't say since I don't work for Microsoft and the OS is still in beta. But if you want to try it, the existing WAIK may do what you want: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10333

Just understand that sysprep probably isn't going work since it was primarily intended for XP and lower OS's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep). But since I can't even evaluate a Windows 8 RTM version I can't really say for sure. Like most people, I have to wait until Windows 8 is released which should be at the end of October (however, I'm not holding my breath given Microsoft's historical delays of past releases).

Hope it helps. (Probably not.)

Comment: ADK is out, it will do the job...http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652